# Excel formula to return a cell value if value is within a text string

Tags: excel

I need a formula that finds a specific alphanumeric code within a text string with no partial match and return the value of that code in A2, see example here, sorry for the link can't post images as I don't have reputation yet, and can't figure how to insert a table here.

[image: Sample data only]
[Excel example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvDsU.jpg)

thanks.

Comment: Nice image. What formula(s) have you tried?

Comment: Thanks for your interest, I have tried this one found in other topic here  =IFERROR(LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(" "&B$1:B$9&" "," "&A1&" "),B$1:B$9),"")     but with modified cells to match mine, but I don't know if it only works for text and not numbers as it gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

In A2 and copied down to suit this formula:

```
  =INDEX(B:B,MATCH(RIGHT(D2,9),B:B,0))
```

applied to your sample data for me returns:

[image]